# Dateformatter Result

Tags: ios, swift, date, dateformatter

Here is my DateFormatter Code

```
 let formatter = DateFormatter()
 formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd"
 let dateString = formatter.string(from: date)
```

Now:

```
po dateString
```

gives the result "May 18"

```
po date gives the result 2021-05-17 18:30:00 +0000
```

This does not make sense to me - why is the Date May 17 2021 being converted to the String May 18?

Comment: `+0000` and a 18h30? Are you in India where the Timezone difference is currently 5:30h? That's normal then, no? It might be 18:30 on the 17 of May in UTC, but in India Time, it means 00:00 on the 18 of May.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Date` object records an instant in time anywhere on the planet.

That instant in time will be on a different calendar day (day/month/year) depending on what time zone you are in.

By default, date formatters work in the device's current time zone.

When you log a Date using `po date` or `print(date)` the default description of a Date displays that date in UTC using the ISO 8601 date format. Depending on the user's time zone, the Date in UTC might be on a different calendar day than it is in the local time zone

If you want to log a date in the user's local time zone, use `po date.description(with: Locale.current)` or `po DateFormatter.localizedString(from: date, dateStyle: .medium, timeStyle: .medium)`

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the current time zone of the formatter used , for 0 based use

```
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
```